# Saving with mongoose to mongodb in a loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to save an object multiple times, with a change to the date field - adding one month per iteration.

A for loop doesn't work due to node async nature.

```
const saveMany = (req, res, obj, data) => {
    let saves = [];
    if (data.frequency === 'monthly') {
         let i = 0;
         for (let i = 0; i < data.reccuring_length; i++) {
            const newEntry = new obj(data);
            if (i != 0) newEntry.created_date.addMonths(1) //using datejs
            newEntry.save((err, entry) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: err
                    });
                }
                saves.push(entry);
            })

        }) //end of for loop
        return res.json(saves)

    } //end of if
}
```

I've seen stuff about promises / the async library but can't make a working implementation (I am new to this though so could be missing something obvious).

Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT: 
[Saving To MongoDB In A Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020439/saving-to-mongodb-in-a-loop)

Found this link which is relevant, but if anyone has other suggestions that would be great.

EDIT 2:

Just realised my code has camelcase and snake case, changing in my code to make all object data snake case.

Comment: use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) so you can call `then` on all promises (after saving everything)

Comment: @molamk Will give it a try. Thanks will feedback if I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do somethings like that:

```
const saveMany = async (req, res, obj, data) => {
let saves = [];
if (data.frequency === 'monthly') {
     let i = 0;
     for (let i = 0; i < data.reccuring_length; i++) {
        const newEntry = new obj(data);
        if (i != 0) newEntry.created_date.addMonths(1) //using datejs
        try{
          const entry= await newEntry.save();
          saves.push(entry);
        } catch(err) {
          return res.status(400).send({ message: err });
        }
    }) //end of for loop
    return res.json(saves)

} //end of if
}
```

Comment: Only problem is that the code doesn't throw an error, it simply just doesn't save anything.

Comment: Hum, ok... Can you copy your "obj" schema and what is inside your "data" object ? Also a call example of the function could help (to see if you pass the model by example). I use this kind of code and it save perfectly my docs. Maybe **reccuring_length** is 0 or **frequency** is not monthly.

Comment: You are correct, works a dream. I was passing recurring_length with a typo so nothing being saved. Thank you so much